# Why does debug output show in WinDbg but not VS2010?

Tags: .net-4.0

We have .NET 4 application that does some logging.

When the application is launched from Studio, there's no output in the Debug view.

When the application is launched from WinDbg, the logging is shown as expected.

I've read that there was a change in .NET 4 preventing the logging from showing up in both Studio and WinDbg, but it doesn't seem to show up in Studio at all now.  Before the solution was upgraded, it did log as expected in VS2008.

Why is the Debug output showing up correctly when launched from WinDbg but not when launched from VS2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a misconfigured log4net.config file.

Added the `<appender>` block and `<appender-ref>` block to reference said appender.

```
<log4net>
  ...
  <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender" >
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <param name="Header" value="[Header]\r\n" />
      <param name="Footer" value="[Footer]\r\n" />
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>
    ...
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```